# VLC video playback issue

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, vlc-media-player

At times video stream in VLC becomes corrupted when playing a file stored on an HDD:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/rfViJaM.png]

I haven't noticed problems with VLC when the video file is located on an SSD.

The video files I play are flawless in technological sense and the corruption occurs seemingly randomly, not at specific points in the video. Other media players such as [MPC-HC](https://mpc-hc.org/) and [mpv](https://mpv.io/)  do not suffer from this issue at all.

The issue has been discussed to great lengths [on the VLC forums](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=117809), but there appears to be no solution aside from [increasing the size of cache](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=117809#p409001), which  has its own set of drawbacks (increased delay).

Comment: broken video stream, it's not vlc's fault.

Comment: @IporSircer: No, the same section can play without issues when restarted; edited the question.